# C base conversion from decimal to ternary

Tags: c, string, algorithm, math

I'm converting an integer value to a ternary number (which is a String). I suspect there should be a better way to achieve this with less computational effort.

My algorithm directly implements the long division method to convert a number between decimal and any base.

```
char *get_ternary_str(int value) {
  char buffer[3] = { "000" };
  int dividend = value;

  int i = 0;
  do {
    int remainder = dividend % 3;
    dividend = dividend / 3;
    buffer[i] = ((char)remainder + '0');
    i++;
  } while(dividend >= 1 && i < 3);

  char temp = buffer[2];
  buffer[2] = buffer[0];
  buffer[0] = temp;

  return buffer;
}
```

Even if in this example the ternary number is 3 digits long, my goal is to make it n-digit long. Suggestions on how to do this to n-digit ternary numbers are also welcome.

Comment: You have three major problems with the function you show: The first is that you forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is important, and means that a string of three characters needs space for four to include the terminator. The second problem is related to the previous, in that you don't terminate the string. The third problem is that you return a pointer to the first element of `buffer`, and once the function returns `buffer` goes out of scope and practically cease to exist, leaving you with a stray and invalid pointer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think the first two problems are no real problems as long as the char array is used as char array and not as cstring (operations on elements and not on whole array).

Comment: @CoryKramer: Almost no other languages are as closely bound together on many levels as C and C++. For me, it is totally OK that he asks for a solution in either language. Also, translating a C solution to C++ is often trivial.

Comment: @ErikAlapää See [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags). The two languages are somewhat compatible, but have completely different library features, idioms, patterns, etc. So it is meaningless to ask for an answer in both, as a proper solution should target only one of those languages.

Comment: @CoryKramer: I have read a lot of these discussions on SO and elsewhere. In my eyes, a lot of the bureaucratic 'C is not a true subset of C++' responses are totally irrelevant for real developers. In many settings, I use C idioms and libraries mixed with C++ idioms and libraries. The design space is enormous, it is just about experience, knowledge and good judgement. And keeping things simple...

Comment: @ThomasSablik From the question: "I'm converting an integer value to a ternary number (which is a ***String***)" (emphasis mine). That seems to indicate that the returned pointer will be used as a string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Ok, my fault.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Yes C & C++ overlap in many ways.  In _this_ case, a key element is `char` buffer management.  For C++, I'd return a `std::string`.  For C I'd use a _compound literal_.  The languages are disjoint concerning these 2 approaches.  A common approach could be found, but that would not be best practice in either.

Comment: @CoryKramer C++ is the natural successor of C. I love the simplicity of C, but I also love STL and RAII. The languages are brothers in arms for speed and love of the machine.

Answer (score 3):

- You should allocate your buffer dynamically using malloc.
- You can initialize your char array with zeros using memset.
- And lastly, you can calculate the char array length mathematically. Ceiling to Log [value] base 3 will give you the character size of your string. And please keep in mind to add an extra char to use null.

Because of you ask for suggestion, i'm not providing code. But, if you need further help, you can indicate on comment.

Comment: `log()` sounds good in math yet not always in code.  `log(value)` has trouble when `value` is 0 or negative.  `log()/log(3)` also is trouble with   powers of 3 where the division does is not exact and just under the expected whole number value.  Recommend to not use `log()`.

Comment: Try `for (int i=1; i<=INT_MAX/3; i *= 3) {
  printf("%.17e\n", log(i)/log(3));
  }` to see unexpected quotients.

Comment: Dear @chux,
 for (int i=1; i<=INT_MAX/3; i *= 3) { printf("%.17e\n", ceil(log((double)i) / log(3.0))); }
This gives me the exact result. Maybe you might not see my ceiling advice. Or there could be a misunderstanding due to my missing sentence.
And, while writing my suggestion, i didn't mention about exceptional cases. You are right. But, i think he/she can do it's control in code. It shouldn't be a big problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Fair enough: To use `ceil()` is a good step.  With some `int value` and various FP concerns, `ceil(log(i)/log(3))` may, from time-to-time provide a one-too-high string size pre-calculation.  Of course if that is used for `malloc()`, or define a VLA, an extra byte rarely hurts.  If used to drive other parts of code, the +1 may fail the code.  Handling FP nuances for essentially an integer problem, I find, increases code porting and maintenance costs.

Answer (score 3):

Code has problems.

**Returning a pointer to a local variable**

Returning a pointer to a local (non-static) variable is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Do not rely on that memory to be valid after the function is complete.

```
char *get_ternary_str(int value) {
  char buffer[3] = ...
  ...
  return buffer;  // UB
}
```

**Fails with negative numbers**

`-1 % 3` --> -1, so `remainder + '0'` will not generate a digit character.

```
int remainder = dividend % 3;
...
buffer[i] = ((char)remainder + '0');
```

**Insufficient space**

`buffer[3]` is too small for a *string* of `"000"` as space is needed for the *null character*.  `buffer[3]` is big enough for an array of 3 digit characters, but certainly a *string* is desired.

```
// char buffer[3] = { "000" };
char buffer[3+1] = { "000" };
```

**Null character never assigned**

Certainly the result should be a *string* which requires a *null character* `'\0'`.  Code  needs to be amended to insure that.

---

> my goal is to make it n-digit long
>   Suggestions on how to do this to n-digit ternary numbers are also welcome.

A `char` buffer is needed to cope with the formed string.  A simple solution is to pass in a buffer pointer large enough for the worse case.  I recommend to also pass in the size of the buffer.

Below is a solution to handle any base 2-36.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Maximum buffer size (worst case: INT_MIN and base 2)
#define ITOA_BASE_N (1 + sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT + 1)

char *itoa_base(char *dest, size_t sz, int i, unsigned base) {
  char buf[ITOA_BASE_N];
  char *s = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];  // set to last character.
  *s = '\0';
  unsigned u = (unsigned) i;  // Use unsigned to cope with INT_MIN ...
  if (i < 0) {
    u = -u;                   // ... as -INT_MIN is UB
  }
  do {
    *(--s) = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[u % base];
    u /= base;
  } while (u);
  if (i < 0) {
    *(--s) = '-';
  }
  size_t size_used = &buf[sizeof buf] - s;
  if (size_used > sz) {
    return NULL;  // or some other error handling.
  }
  return memcpy(dest, s, size_used);
}
```

The test employs a *compound literal* for temporary storage, but one could pass in a fixed buffer if desired.

```
#define TO_BASE3(x) itoa_base((char [ITOA_BASE_N]){0}, ITOA_BASE_N, (x), 3)

void test3(int x) {
  char *s = TO_BASE3(x);
  // do stuff with `s`, it is valid for until the end of this block
  printf("base10:%11d base3:'%s'\n", x, s);
}

int main(void) {
  test3(0);
  test3(1);
  test3(42);
  test3(-81);
  test3(INT_MAX);
  test3(INT_MIN);
}
```

Output

```
base10:          0 base3:'0'
base10:          1 base3:'1'
base10:         42 base3:'1120'
base10:        -81 base3:'-10000'
base10: 2147483647 base3:'12112122212110202101'
base10:-2147483648 base3:'-12112122212110202102'
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I always forget that `-INT_MIN > INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Bob__: `-INT_MIN` may have undefined behavior. `INT_MIN < -INT_MAX` is defined and true on 2's complement architectures.

Comment: @chqrlie The comment was badly written. I meant that the absolute *value* (the number, not the `int` representation) of INT_MIN  is greater then INT_MAX, so I agree with the UB.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, [I feel your pain](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bill_Clinton#1990s).  Text-like code has that unfortunate effect.  Now if a compiler could just have a  `do_what_i_want_not_what_i_code(code);` function ....  ;-)

Comment: @chux I upvoted your answer. I'd make it the correct answer but I think you missed something: the leading zeroes from the non-affected digits. Do you think it would be a good practice to start the buffer with all '0's in order to achieve this? and is there any trick or efficient way to do it without filling it with a loop? Thank you.

Comment: @chux last question: why do you reserve 'sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT + 2' space? Since this is a String, wouldn't be enough to reserve space for 'sizeof(char) * base + 2'?

Comment: @Tmvaz Aside from the number 0, common practice is to omit leading zeros. Leading zeros with a signed type like `int` is _very_ unusual.  If you want leadings zeros, then how many? `n`.  Is that fixed at compile time or variable?   Should negative values have the same amount of leading zeros as positive ones?

Comment: @Tmvaz Rewritten:  With a 32-bit `int`, in base 2, and `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` is max number of bits in an `int`,  `INT_MIN` requires `"-10000000000000000000000000000000"` (1 + 32 + 1) `char`.  This is worst case.

Answer (score 1):

I allocate dynamic memory in the `main` function and pass a pointer to the function. This way I can manage the memory. For each allocation you need a deallocation. I allocate 1 element more than string length for string termination. You algorithm is nearly unchanged. I changed the index of the buffer to avoid reordering of buffer elements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void get_ternary_str(char* buffer, int value, unsigned int n) {
  int dividend = value;

  int i = 0;
  do {
    int remainder = dividend % 3;
    dividend = dividend / 3;
    buffer[n - 1 - i] = ((char)remainder + '0');
    i++;
  } while(i < n);

  buffer[i] = 0;
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    int value = 31;
    get_ternary_str(buffer, value, n - 1);

    printf("%s", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

With the idea from Y.Doktur and here is the same code with dynamic length. I use a pointer to pointer to pass and receive a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char* get_ternary_str(unsigned int value) {
  int n = value > 2 ? 1 + floor(log(value) / log(3)) : 1;
  char* buffer = (char*) malloc((n+1) * sizeof(char));
  int dividend = value;

  int i = 0;
  do {
    int remainder = dividend % 3;
    dividend = dividend / 3;
    buffer[n - 1 - i] = ((char)remainder + '0');
    i++;
  } while(i < n);

  buffer[i] = 0;
  return buffer;
}

int main() {

  int value = 31;
  char* buffer = get_ternary_str(value);

  printf("%s", buffer);
  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you use a double pointer to the receiving char buffer since its an one-dimentional array? And why can't we allocate inside the function and pass the pointer to its calling function? Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it in my answer

Comment: `log(value)` has trouble when `value` is 0 or negative.

Comment: @chux: Thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173921/c-base-conversion-from-decimal-to-ternary/50174708?noredirect=1#comment87378614_50175103) to see if you always get the expected quotient.  Using `log()` to determine `log3()` is prone to computational unexpectednesses.  (i.e. the wrong answer)

Comment: @chux: Can you provide an example, where this will produce an error?

Comment: What was your result of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173921/c-base-conversion-from-decimal-to-ternary/50174708?noredirect=1#comment87378614_50175103)?  Did it always provide the correct `log3()`?  If it did, please report the value of  integer constant `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` which tells about FP precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can trade some memory space for calculation time, if that is your concern, using a simple and small look-up table.

Consider this C++ (earlier versions of your question asked for ideas in that language too) snippet as an example of the algorithm I'm proposing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

std::string ternary_from(int value)
{ 
    // The idea is to elaborate three figures (in base 3) at a time
    constexpr int dim = 3 * 3 * 3;

    // Note the values, are "reversed"
    static const std::array<std::string, dim> inner_parts {
        "000", "100", "200", "010", "110", "210", "020", "120", "220", 
        "001", "101", "201", "011", "111", "211", "021", "121", "221", 
        "002", "102", "202", "012", "112", "212", "022", "122", "222" 
    };

    static const std::array<std::string, dim> parts {
        "", "1", "2", "01", "11", "21", "02", "12", "22", 
        "001", "101", "201", "011", "111", "211", "021", "121", "221", 
        "002", "102", "202", "012", "112", "212", "022", "122", "222" 
    };

    if ( value == 0 )
        return std::string{"0"};

    std::string result;

    // Thanks @Chux for recalling that -INT_MIN is UB
    unsigned tmp = value;
    if ( value < 0 )
        tmp = -tmp;

    // note that 'dim' = 27, so you are performing a third of the calculations
    while (tmp >= dim)
    {
        unsigned remainder = tmp % dim;
        // concatenating a string at the end is easier...
        result += inner_parts[remainder];
        tmp = tmp / dim;
    }
    result += parts[tmp];

    if (value < 0)
        result += '-';

    // now the string needs to be reversed. e.g. 3 -> 10(3), not 01 
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> tests {
        42, -8, 0, 81, 27, -28, std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
    };

    std::cout << "   decimal           ternary\n";
    for (int i : tests)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(12) << i << std::setw(23) << ternary_from(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

It outputs

```
   decimal           ternary
          42                   1120
          -8                    -22
           0                      0
          81                  10000
          27                   1000
         -28                  -1001
  2147483647   12112122212110202101
 -2147483648  -12112122212110202102
```